# Angular ngx datatable hides some column content

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Hi am using ngx datatable in my project,the column automatically cuts long datas, how to show entire data in column, for reference here with I have attached the screen shot [image]

the actual url for second row is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118910/ngx-datatable-vertical-scroll-with-rowheight-set-to-auto` but in table some datas are hidden, below is my datatable property 
         `class="material fixed-header"
          [headerHeight]="50"
          [limit]="10"
          [columnMode]="'force'"
          [footerHeight]="50"
          [rowHeight]="'auto'"
          [rows]="rows"
          [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
          [selected]="selected"
          [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
          [scrollbarH]="true"`
Anyone help to solve my issue

Comment: Did you try setting [columnMode]="'flex'"?

Comment: yes tried , if using mode flex means it shows entire datas but its get affected the other column datas

Answer (score 0):

From ngx docs about force mode.
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/docs/api/column/modes.md

> The proportional widths should never fall below min size if specified.

When you specify the width of each column they need to sum up to the size of your screen.
Eg. if the screen size is 400, you could have 4 columns with width 100.

If you want to support smaller screens you could set the columns to be smaller, or use vertical scroll after a certain breakpoint. But maybe the easiest would be to use flex.
[scrollbarH]="smallScreen"

I also have had troubles combining [scrollbarH] with rowheight. You could test choosing one of them.